# One-liner to install Python 3.9 on Amazon Linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, python

Is there a simple, one-liner `yum`-like command to install Python 3.9 on Amazon Linux?

> ```
> [root@ip-10-0-0-182 ~]# yum install python39
> Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
> No package python39 available.
> Error: Nothing to do
> ```

The top hit on Google is currently [this article](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-9-on-amazon-linux/) which tells you to download sources and build it yourself. I don't want that.

Comment: you can download python3.9 rpm package then install it

Comment: Now in Amazon Linux 2023, finally, you can do just that.

Comment: @AmitNaidu please submit your comment as the answer!

Answer (score 3):

this is the only solution I found in the web which works. Strangely it is hard to find...

https://techviewleo.com/how-to-install-python-on-amazon-linux/

or you to install 3.8 on Amazon Linux 2, you need to have amazon-linux-extras repository installed.
`$ which amazon-linux-extras`
`/usr/bin/amazon-linux-extras`
If the command doesn’t return any output, then install the package that will configure the repository:

`sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras`
Confirm if you can see Python 3.8 packages available on the repository.

`$ amazon-linux-extras | grep -i python`

python3.8                available    [ =stable ]
As can be seen from the output python3.8 package is available for installation.
Enable the repository before using it.

`sudo amazon-linux-extras enable python3.8`
Issue the commands shown below in the terminal to install Python 3.8 on Amazon Linux 2 server.

`sudo yum install python3.8`

Comment: Requester is asking about 3.9, not 3.8.